# Curl cant download Composer installer, complaining about 8888 port

Tags: php, linux, curl, composer-php

The steps to install composer globally is there: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

The  commands there are:

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
`mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

but The original  the  command: 
`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` 
returns:  `curl: (7) Failed connect to getcomposer.org:8888; Connection refused`

if put `:80` on url  the  command: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org:80/installer | php`
returns: `curl: (7) Failed connect to getcomposer.org:8888; Connection refused`

if tell port with `-P`  the  command:  `curl -sS -P 80  https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
returns:  `curl: (7) Failed connect to getcomposer.org:8888; Connection refused`

Someone here: [Installing composer using vagrant, hhvm, and Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471864/installing-composer-using-vagrant-hhvm-and-ubuntu-14-04)
told to try wget I tried and the results:

The command: `wget https://getcomposer.org/installer`
returns:    `--2014-08-29 19:13:24--  https://getcomposer.org/installer  Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888... failed: Connection refused`.

The command: `wget https://getcomposer.org:80/installer

returns:    --2014-08-29 19:13:40--  https://getcomposer.org:80/installer  Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888... failed: Connection refused`.

Im installing it on a Linux Mint Debian Edition and it complain about port 8888
I can ping `getcomposer.org` and `telnet getcomposer.org:80`
Someone can see what im doing wrong?
Someone voting against this question but is unable to tell what is wrong with it

Comment: Curl should be connecting to getcomposer.org on port 443 as its a https website.  What is the output of     `curl -v https://getcomposer.org/installer -o /dev/null` ?

Comment: This looks like a local proxy to me. Are there any environment variables related to "proxy" defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a perfect answer but it solved for me.

just hit the url

```
https://getcomposer.org/installer
```

it'll download a file name "installer", 
Now go to the download folder where it downloaded

Run this command

```
php installer
```

It'll give you new file composer.phar

This is the exact file that you will get from this command

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Comment: Hi @gsjha I did like you mentioned, but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

Fot some reason Curl try using ipv6 to download compose, and the result is a time out.

try this:
echo ipv4 >> ~/.curlrc

then try again:
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

Comment: ipv6 is disabled on my network - this solved my problem.